# What buildings at the end of the Fallout TV series trailer don't exist in 2023?

Tags: real-location, fallout, fallout-tv-series

At the end of the upcoming Fallout TV series [first trailer](https://youtu.be/0kQ8i2FpRDk?si=03deBR5lneBtYrsl) at the 2:05 mark. The skyline of Los Angeles is shown during the explosion of what appear to be several nuclear bombs.

If this is the start of the Nuclear War that is the precursor to the Fallout franchise, this would be Saturday, October 23, 2077, which is when the great war is believed to have happened.

The skyline shows [Griffith Observatory](https://griffithobservatory.org/) in the lower left-hand corner and what may be Western Canyon Road in the right of the frame.

[image: la 2077]

**Which of the buildings in this image do not exist in the current timeframe (2023) and are additions for the 2077 skyline?**

Comment: The same view (approximately) on Google Earth -  https://earth.google.com/web/search/Griffith+Observatory,+East+Observatory+Road,+Los+Angeles,+CA,+USA/@34.11866107,-118.29985691,347.56904137a,738.77721846d,35y,137.89253772h,83.73263384t,0r/data=CigiJgokCWTmrlxbwTpAEcVI1MPlvinAGSVsupLsfElAIVQTwnKIDE3AOgMKATA

Answer (score 3):

This image is at a slightly different angle but shows that all these foreground buildings dont exist currently.

[image: Screen shot from the trailer of LA in 2077. Foreground buildings highlighted]

This image is from 2022:
[image: Photo of LA in 2022 with foreground highlighted]